# Why won't a child thread that is create by cloned thread output anything to terminal after the parent thread outputs or after it sleeps?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, ubuntu

I'm learning to use the `clone` method **(only CLONE_VM)** to create children threads with c on ubuntu18. When the parent thread has no `sleep` method or `printf`, the child thread can run normally after the parent exits. Unfortunately, when the parent thread has a `sleep` or `printf`, the child would be killed as parent exits. I don't know how it is supposed to work.

Here is my code:

```
int child_proc(void *args)
{
    int a = *((int *)args);
    //sleep(1);
    printf("child receive a arg: %d\n", a);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int cpid, arg = 45, clone_flags = CLONE_VM;
    char *stack = malloc(MAXSPACE); //space
    printf("arg -> %d\n", arg);
    cpid = clone((void *)child_proc, &(stack[MAXSPACE-1]), clone_flags, (void *)(&arg));
    sleep(2); 
    printf("cpid %d\n", cpid);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the result:

```
$ ./clone.o
arg -> 45
child receive a arg: 45
cpid 4685
```

The result looks good, when I change the sleep method:

```
int child_proc(void *args)
{
    int a = *((int *)args);
    sleep(1);
    printf("child receive a arg: %d\n", a);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int cpid, arg = 45, clone_flags = CLONE_VM;
    char *stack = malloc(MAXSPACE);
    printf("arg -> %d\n", arg);
    cpid = clone((void *)child_proc, &(stack[MAXSPACE-1]), clone_flags, (void *)(&arg));
    //sleep(2);
    printf("cpid %d\n", cpid);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems normal:

```
$ ./clone.o
arg -> 45
cpid 4845
```

The child thread didn't output, because the parent has exited but when I delete all of the `sleep` methods and `printf` methods in parent:

```
int child_proc(void *args)
{
    int a = *((int *)args);
    sleep(1);
    printf("child receive a arg: %d\n", a);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int cpid, arg = 45, clone_flags = CLONE_VM;
    char *stack = malloc(MAXSPACE);
    //printf("arg -> %d\n", arg);
    cpid = clone((void *)child_proc, &(stack[MAXSPACE-1]), clone_flags, (void *)(&arg));
    //sleep(2);
    //printf("cpid %d\n", cpid);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems pretty weird:

```
$./clone.o
$ child receive a arg: 32767
```

First line quits immediately, and the second line comes up. 
After 1 second, the child thread's output come up too. 
After the output on second line I can type a command directly. I don't know how it is supposed to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Without the `CLONE_THREAD` the cloned process is in a different thread group. When the main thread exits, its thread group is killed (as `exit()` is actually [`exit_group()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html)). The cloned thread is not killed, so it continues running, until it exits as well. Whenever the process the shell started exits (here, the main thread group), you get back to the command prompt in the shell. Try running 'sh -c '(sleep 1; echo 45) &'`: it does a very similar thing.

Comment: In case 2, the child thread is not killed, but also print nothing. Why?

Comment: The C library expects threads to be created using `pthread_create()`. The standard I/O functions use internal locking to avoid mixing the output from two threads. I suspect that the C library does something when creating threads, and without that, some of the C library internals get wonky. It could be something as simple as missing thread-local storage (TLS) or initializing it. To check if this something like that is indeed the case, try `dprintf(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)` instead of `printf(...)`.